# 3x3 CSS grid: how to make center div the only one with a fixed height/width?

Tags: css, layout, html, grid, center

I've been struggling for awhile trying to make a 3x3 grid layout in which the center div has a fixed width & height, and the rest grow to fit the window size as needed, but I can never get the non-center divs to behave. I've found some solutions that worked for a two-column layout, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt them to three. Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/WGaVH/

New to CSS here, so any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display table makes this easy:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .grid3x3 {
        display:table;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div {
        display:table-row;
        width:100%;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div:nth-child(2) {
        height: 100px;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div > div {
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div > div:nth-child(2) {
        width:100px;
    }

    div {
        outline: 1px solid orange;
    }


</style>
<div class="grid3x3">
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I worked out: http://jsfiddle.net/WGaVH/21/

I simplified the html some. There is some overlapping of div's, which could create some challenges depending on what you are planning to do with the background (though not anything that couldn't be worked out with possibly another nested div).

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="top left"><p><span id="topLeftContent">1</span></p></div>
    <div class="top mid"><p><span id="topCenterContent">2</span></p></div>
    <div class="top right"><p><span id="topRightContent">3</span></p></div>

    <div class="main left"><p><span id="mainLeftContent">4</span></p></div>
    <div class="main mid"><p><span id="mainCenterContent">
        <object width="84" height="60" align="middle"></object>5
    </span></p></div>
    <div class="main right"><p><span id="mainRightContent">6</span></p></div>


    <div class="bottom left"><p><span id="bottomLeftContent">7</span></p></div>
    <div class="bottom mid"><p><span id="bottomCenterContent">8</span></p></div>
    <div class="bottom right"><p><span id="bottomRightContent">9</span></p></div>

</div>
```

**CSS** (colors just for demo)

```
    html, body{width:100%;height:100%;}
    html,body {margin:0;padding:0}

    #wrapper{width:100%;height:100%;background:#bbffbb;overflow:hidden;}

    .top, .main, .bottom {
       text-align:center;
       float: left;
       position: relative;
       background-color: #FFFFCC;
    }

   .top {
       height: 50%;
       margin-bottom: -30px;
   }
   .top p {
       margin-bottom: 30px;
   }
   .main {
       height: 60px;
       z-index: 2;
   }
   .bottom {
       height: 50%;
       margin-top: -30px;
   }
   .bottom p {
       margin-top: 30px;
   }
   .left {
       width: 50%;
       margin-right: -42px;        
   }
   .left p {
       margin-right: 42px;
   }
   .mid {
       width: 84px;
       z-index: 2;
   }
   .right {
       width: 50%;
       margin-left: -42px;
    }
   .right p {
       margin-left: 42px;
   }
   .main.mid {
       z-index: 3;
       background-color: #CCFFFF;
   }
   .mid {
       background-color: #FFFFFF;
   }
   .main {
       background-color: #FFCCFF;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/WgF7Z/1/.

All the divs on the page uses percentage widths except the center div.  Maybe it could kickstart some ideas for you.

The trick to avoid overlapping in this example is setting a min height/width on the wrapper div that is 3x's the height/width of your fixed center div.

Also, if CSS3 is an option for your project, look into [The CSS 3 Flexible Box Model](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/)

Comment: Percentage sizes is not what was asked for.

Comment: Yes, and in my response I clearly state the center div is not using percentages.